# How To Determine When ListView is Done Populating

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to manipulate a ListView's children when it is done loading, but I can't seem to find a way to find out when this happens.  When I set the adapter of my ListView, the method returns immediately, but the population of it's children views happens asynchronously.  Is there a way to handle the event when my list is full of views?

Comment: "I need to manipulate a ListView's children when it is done loading" -- that would be rather unusual. More commonly, you will need to put this logic in your adapter itself. Otherwise, once the user scrolls, your "manipulations" are undone.

Comment: I need to scroll to a random item in the list once the list is done loading.  Whenever I attempt to do this before the view is loaded, there are no child views.

Comment: The precise timing of when the `ListView` contents are populated is undocumented, and as such you should not rely upon it.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the advice, your comment solved my problem. Just do whatever you need to do in the adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do a periodic polling to see if the list has been populated: write a while() loop to check once in a while. Or you could wait for a fixed amount of time (say 30 ms) before doing your next operation. These are not recommended methods, but should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getChildCount()` to retrieve the shown views and also use a counter to keep track of how many views have been loaded asynchronously. I think I understand your question right.